# InvalidElementStateException while doing send_key or clear()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

```
url='https://jwt.io/'
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")
time.sleep(5)
element_data='/html/body/section[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]'
#hightlight_body=\
element_data1=driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_data).clear()
```

Error:
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state
(Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why `.clear` method throws `InvalidElementStateException`. But was able to clear and type some text through `Actionchains`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://jwt.io/")
action = ActionChains(driver)
textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='js-payload']//div[@class='CodeMirror-code']")
textbox.click()
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("a").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
action.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).perform()
action.send_keys("Sample text").perform()

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

When this site is opened "Accept cookies" pop-up appears, so you have first to close it.
This element is inside an iframe.
So you first have to switch to the iframe, close the pop-up, switch to the default content and then you can continue with your code.
Your code should be something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url='https://jwt.io/'
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'iframe[title="TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager"]')))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text(),'Accept All')]'))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")
time.sleep(5)
element_data='/html/body/section[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]'
#hightlight_body=\
element_data1=driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_data).clear()
```